# How does one programatically map object values in Zod?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-conversion, zod

For the following schema:

```
const z_BaseCustomer = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number()
});

const pizzas = [
  {
    value: "pn_pizza",
    label: "Pineapple Pizza",
  },
  {
    value: "vgt_pizza",
    label: "Vegetarian Pizza",
  },
  {
    value: "sc_pizza",
    label: "Sicilian Pizza"
  },
  {
    value: "mg_pizza",
    label: "Pizza Margherita"
  },
  {
    value: "ny_pizza",
    label: "New York-Style Pizza"
  }
] as const;

type FavoritePizzaValue = typeof pizzas[number]['value'];
type FavoritePizzaLabel = typeof pizzas[number]['label'];
const z_FavoritePizzaValue = z.custom<FavoritePizzaValue>;
const z_FavoritePizzaLabel = z.custom<FavoritePizzaLabel>;

const drinks = [
  {
    value: "dr_cola",
    label: "Coca Cola"
  },
  {
    value: "dr_mtdew",
    label: "Mountain Dew"
  }
] as const;

type FavoriteDrinkValue = typeof drinks[number]['value'];
type FavoriteDrinkLabel = typeof drinks[number]['label'];
const z_FavoriteDrinkValue = z.custom<FavoriteDrinkValue>;
const z_FavoriteDrinkLabel = z.custom<FavoriteDrinkLabel>;


const z_ServerCustomer = z_BaseCustomer.extend({
  favorite_pizza: z_FavoritePizzaValue(),
  favorite_drink: z_FavoriteDrinkValue()
});

const z_ClientCustomer = z_BaseCustomer.extend({
  favorite_pizza: z_FavoritePizzaLabel(),
  favorite_drink: z_FavoriteDrinkLabel()
});

type ServerCustomer = z.infer<typeof z_ServerCustomer>;
type ClientCustomer = z.infer<typeof z_ClientCustomer>;
```

My goal is to map objects of these two types to each other, such that the data in `ServerCustomer` is stored in my database and `ClientCustomer` is rendered in the browser.

Is there a better way than just..?:

```
const CustomerUnionSchema = z.discriminatedUnion("favorite_pizza", [
  z_ServerCustomer, z_ClientCustomer
]).transform(customer => {
  const ret = {
    name: customer.name,
    age: customer.age,
  }
  for(var i in pizzas){
    customer.favorite_pizza === pizzas[i].value
    ? ret.favorite_pizza = pizzas[i].label
    : ret.favorite_pizza = pizzas[i].value
  }
  for(var i in drinks){
    customer.favorite_drink === drinks[i].value
    ? ret.favorite_drink = drinks[i].label
    : ret.favorite_drink = drinks[i].value
  }
  return ret;
});
```

Searching through the [Zod documentation](https://zod.dev/) returned nothing, same on here. Is there a way Zod can infer the mapping of these types? Moreover, should I rather change my approach to typing my data? What would be considered best?

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572), and don't abuse the conditional operator for `if` statements!

Comment: You most like want to use a mapping object (`satisfies Record<FavoritePizzaValue, FavoritePizzaLabel>` or `Map<FavoritePizzaValue, FavoritePizzaLabel>`), not an array of tuples. With an `as const` mapping, you can also infer the types.

Comment: Your code in the `transform` does not appear to work. What do you actually want it to do? If you want to map the two types to each other, you should have *two* functions, one for mapping forth and one for mapping back. And you probably should declare normal functions for that, not use zod at all. A union does not really make sense to me.